# hover hyperlink colour not working when rolled over

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have css:

```
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CCC;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #fff;
}
a:active {

    text-decoration: none;
        color: #CCC;
}
```

the hover does not work when i first load the webpage however when i click on the hyperlink then go back the hover then works. What is the issue.

Comment: Maybe you just needed to refresh the cache with the updated CSS file?

Comment: Any possibility that your browser is caching the stylesheet? You should turn caching off in your browser for development.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/D9UEK/

Comment: yes i emptied cache still not working

Comment: when you include your css, use versioning to prevent caching: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css?v=1234" type="text/css" />`

Comment: This happens in **all** browsers?  Link to a demo page, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is some extra CSS hanging around somewhere... You could try resetting CSS at the beginning of your file:

```
a:visited, a:hover, a:active { text-decoration:none; }
```

Comment: Maybe we should wait for more information from the OP before taking the shotgun approach to troubleshooting.

Comment: locationed after 

a:link {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

Test your code at the seperate page of your project, I think it works, if it works, there is something else in your project that makes it incorrect, I mean external css